# How to delete file from removable sd card (second external storage)?

Tags: android, delete-file

I am trying to delete a file (PATH_TO_SD_CARD/DCIM/1.PDF) on android 9 from my sd card (removable).

**1. I get the volumePaths where the 2nd one is my sd card.**

```
private static String[] getVolumePaths(Context context) {
    String[] volumes = null;
    StorageManager managerStorage = (StorageManager) context.getSystemService(Context.STORAGE_SERVICE);
    if (managerStorage == null) {
        return volumes;
    }
    try {
        return (String[]) managerStorage.getClass().getMethod("getVolumePaths", new Class[0]).invoke(managerStorage, new Object[0]);
    } catch (NoSuchMethodException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        return volumes;
    } catch (IllegalArgumentException e2) {
        e2.printStackTrace();
        return volumes;
    } catch (IllegalAccessException e3) {
        e3.printStackTrace();
        return volumes;
    } catch (InvocationTargetException e4) {
        e4.printStackTrace();
        return volumes;
    }
}

    String[] volumePaths = getVolumePaths(getContext());
    Log.v("VOLUME1: ", "-> "+volumePaths[0]);
    Log.v("VOLUME2: ", "-> "+volumePaths[1]);
```

**LocCat:**

```
2019-07-19 17:06:15.577 13257-13257/com.spicysoftware.spicypdfreader V/VOLUME2:: -> /storage/2585-1513
```

**2. I check if the file exists which returns true**

```
Log.v("FILE EXISTS?", "-> "+new File("/storage/2585-1513/DCIM/1.PDF").exists());
```

**LogCat**

```
2019-07-19 17:06:16.577 13257-13257/com.spicysoftware.spicypdfreader V/FILE EXISTS? -> true
```

**3.1 I am trying to delete the file**

But this way does not work, why?

```
new File("/storage/2585-1513/DCIM/1.PDF").delete();
```

**3.2 I am trying to delete the file via DOCUMENT_FILE_TREE**

```
// call for document tree dialog
Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_OPEN_DOCUMENT_TREE);
startActivityForResult(intent, 123);

@Override
public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    switch (requestCode) {
        case 123:
            if (resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK) {
                String strFilePath = data.getData().getPath()+"/DCIM/1.PDF";
                try {
                    if(new File(strFilePath).delete()){
                        Log.v("FILE", "DELETED");
                    }else{
                        Log.v("FILE", "NOT DELETED");
                    }
                }catch (Exception e){
                    Log.v("ERROR: ", "-> "+e);
                }
            }
            break;
    }
}
```

**LogCat**

```
2019-07-19 17:23:20.523 14343-14343/com.spicysoftware.spicypdfreader V/FILE: NOT DELETED
```

So my question is: How to delete file from removable sd card (second external storage)? This is so weird...
I was 2 days on this problem and didn't find any solution how to delete a file on this sd card...

I also used the storage access framework which did not work.
If it is the only way to handle that pls add an example.

Answer (score 6):

> How to delete file from removable sd card (second external storage)?

You don't. You do not have read/write access to arbitrary locations on removable storage.

> I also used the storage access framework which did not work

Not really. You used `ACTION_OPEN_DOCUMENT_TREE` to get a `Uri`, then tried to turn it into a `File`. That will not work, as a `Uri` is not a file.

The simplest solution is:

- Use `ACTION_OPEN_DOCUMENT`
- Pass the `Uri` that you get (`data.getData()` from your question) and pass that to `DocumentFile.fromSingleUri()`
- Call `delete()` on that `DocumentFile`

Comment: Thx for your answer. I'll try it. But first ylu say it's not possible and then that I have to use ACTION_OPEN_DOCUMENT to do so. So it is possible to delete files like in many file explorers. :)

Comment: @MSeiz5: Pre-installed file managers have additional rights granted to them by the device manufacturer. Everyone else needs to go through the Storage Access Framework in one way or another. Some file managers will use `ACTION_OPEN_DOCUMENT_TREE` for that, then use `DocumentFile.fromTreeUri()` and `listFiles()` to get the contents of that tree.

Comment: Yeah that's what I meant. It is possible to do. But not directly like on the external storage.

Comment: I can't fine any example in the web how to use it. Can you please explain it to me with a snippet?

Answer (score 1):

By security, you can access to your SD Card but **you can only write & read files into the directory that was created for your app or files inside the directories created by your app** (using `WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE` permission).

[image]

for example if your  external storage path is

```
/storage/13257-13257/
```

and your app package name is `com.spicysoftware.spicypdfreader`

You can access and delete files created inside this path:

```
 /storage/13257-13257/com.spicysoftware.spicypdfreader
```

By the way i suggest to you use `ContextCompat.getExternalFilesDirs(context, null)` to get the path of your /files directory  `/storage/13257-13257/com.spicysoftware.spicypdfreader/files`
.

Example:

```
 File[] storages = ContextCompat.getExternalFilesDirs(context, null);
Log.i(TAG, "storage[0]: " + storages[0]);
Log.i(TAG, "storage[1]: " + storages[1]);
```

---

in conclusion, you can delete files here:

```
new File("/storage/13257-13257/com.spicysoftware.spicypdfreader/files/1.PDF").delete();
```

or here (outside `/files` directory):

```
new File("/storage/13257-13257/com.spicysoftware.spicypdfreader/1.PDF").delete();
```

but is not possible to do this:

```
new File("/storage/13257-13257/DCIM/1.PDF").delete();
```